# How do I pass the image object into the onclick function being assigned to it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if that question is confusing, I'm self-learning javascript. I'm dynamically generating image thumbnails and I want to be able to enlarge the image when the user clicks on the thumbnails.  My code to create the image tag and assign the onclick function looks like...

```
var imageTag = "<img onclick=\"enlargeImage()\" class=\"thumb\" src=\"" + photoURL + "\" />"; 
document.getElementById("image-thumbnail").innerHTML = imageTag;
```

With that code above, my thumbnail gets displayed and when the user clicks on it, the `enlargeImage()` function is called.  My question is, how can I access the image object that was clicked inside the `enlargeImage()` function?  I tried accessing the `this` object inside the function hoping it pointed to the image that was clicked, but `this` referred to the entire page, not the image that was clicked. I'd like to be able access the `src` attribute, as well as, change the style attributes of the image thumbnail.  I should also note that eventually there will be multiple images which is why I need this dynamic behavior.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. The easiest is to simply add a a parameter to the `enlargeImage()` function and pass it a `this` reference when you call it.

```
var imageTag = "<img onclick=\"enlargeImage(this)\" class=\"thumb\" src=\"" + photoURL + "\" />";
```

Then in the function...

```
function enlargeImage(img) {
  alert(img.src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out jQuery, since it has a lot of wrappers and handlers for dealing with this stuff, and has a lot of momentum recently.

To be more specific to your question, you can just pass "this" to your function:

```
var imageTag = "<img onclick=\"enlargeImage(this)\" class=\"thumb\" src=\"" + photoURL + "\" />";
```

and then in your function you'll have access to the src tag:

```
function enlargeImage(img){
  alert(img.src);
}
```

Comment: It's almost like you copied my answer. :-)

Answer (score -1):

`function enlargeImage(img)
{
    var src = img.src;
}`